# Javascript handling PHP in Wordpress index.html causing loading issues, not matching fiddle code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site where I have retrieved data from the wordpress database using a php script called within index.php.

I want to handle the data acquired through the php script with a JavaScript/jQuery script that will format the data.

The issue is that the code I am using works in JS Fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/ocmLe17o/6/) works; it logs the correct raw variable from the HTML and parses it successfully.  However, in Wordpress when I include the .js file running the said code in the functions.php file and call the php script, I get no an undefined output console.logged as the svg_links_parsed variable.  ("VM691:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()"

I suspect the issue may be with the order in which Wordpress loads scripts, and I've tried enqueueing the script after the php including, but I get the same issue.

TL;DR: It works in Fiddle but not wordpress, how do I guarantee the script fires after the php code is inserted if in Wordpress the header is called first and the script is in the header?

Example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
<input type='hidden' id='cover_links' value='["img\/TTEST_1.svg","img\foo.svg","img\/Bar.svg","img\/Derp.svg"]'>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var raw_src = jQuery("input").val();

console.log(raw_src); //In Fiddle this logs the input string, in Wordpress it's Undefined!

var svg_links_parsed = JSON.parse(raw_src);

document.write(svg_links_parsed);
```

Comment: Why bother sticking it into a input tag when you can write it directly to javascript? Do a <script> tag and stick your data in a JS variable in your index.php.

Comment: If `document.write()` is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Comment: `jQuery("input")` is an unselictive qualifier, is there more than one <input> field? Shouldn't you select by id `jQuery("input#cover_links")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to wait until the page is loaded to be sure the script runs after the input tag is loaded into the dom.  Stick your code in a document ready :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // do stuff after page is loaded. 
});
```